# R barplot of count: Skewed data with columns with large counts and columns with zero or few counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

The following code draws a barplot of count of x elements with y-axis in log scale.

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(scales)

myData <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep(1, 22500), 
        rep(2, 6000), 
        rep(3, 8000), 
        rep(4, 5000), 
        rep(11, 86), 
        rep(16, 15), 
        rep(31, 1), 
        rep(32, 1), 
        rep(47, 1))
)

ggplot(myData, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 0.5)+
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label = ..count..), vjust = -1, size=3)+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(seq(1:47)))
```

Below is the plot:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How do I remove the x-axis tick marks/labels for those columns with zero count?
2. How do I show the values of column `31`, `32`, `47` better? (those with count 1)
3. How do I just label the count of the tallest column? (`22500` of column `1` in this case)

Comment: Some of your questions are quite opinion-based, in particular the parts where you ask about what is a *"a better way to represent this data"*. There is nothing wrong with those questions in general, but here on Stack Overflow opinion-based questions are off-topic. It's also generally advisable to ask one question at a time. I would suggest rephrasing your questions to focus on one particular issue.

Comment: PS. You can find answers to some of your sub-questions here on SO; e.g. how to add labels to bargraphs has definitely been asked before.

Comment: I am new to data visualization, and I realize my graph is quite sparse, I am not sure if my way is the best. 
Also, I have added the labels because I have read those answers. My question is  how to remove some labels/ or add the initial labels selectively.

Comment: I understand; but as I said, opinion-based questions are OT here on SO. Also, I can guarantee that adhering to the one-question-at-a-time rule will lead to more and better (as in targeted) responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be for you to add a border color, which would help highlight that there is at least something in those parts of the graph:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  myData %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  count()

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = n)) +
  geom_col(color = "cyan4", fill = "cyan3") +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(x == 1), aes(label = n, y = n + 10000)) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. How do I add x-axis tick/label to columns with value only?

Comment: I don't know how advisable that is, but you could add this to the end of the code: ` +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df %>% pull(x)) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )`

Comment: thank you, that works nicely. Could you advise why is that not advisable? I mean, my x-axis loosk very cluttered, because there are many ticks. (But this could also be solved by having a specific interval, however then the column `47` won't be ticked, since it's not in any interval steps)